# The phone is stuck in download mode and gives error verifying vbmeta image. The device is a205f samsung

Tags: samsung, odin, magisk

The phone had magisk pre installed and I tried to flash a stock rom and after that I manually locked the bootloader from the download mode. Phone is stuck on download mode, odin unable to flash any firmware. It just gives re partition fail error. Device is A205F. Please help?

Comment: with locked bootloader you can only flash official ROM from Odin or Heimdall, congratulation to your first brick https://gsmxt.com/rom-combination-galaxy-a20-sm-a205

Comment: I had this exact thing happen to me on a Galaxy S20 FE. @alecxs How can I flash official ROM from Odin when Odin unable to flash any firmware?

Comment: @hdsenevi try to flash *vbmeta_samsung.img* from Heimdall, then try Odin again. post your solution as answer

Answer (score 1):

you should extract ap file and out recovery.img.lz4 and change it to recovery.img.tar,at first flash pit file then  flash recovery.img.tar (uncheck reboot) then go to recovery and reset factory your device. it works for me.